# Error response when trying to send JSON body using HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, json, http

I need to send body parameters using JSON. I'm working with Printify APIs.
I keep getting error response from server, that my body parameters are empty.

This is the command I'm trying to create:

`POST https://api.printify.com/v1/uploads/images.json`

it needs to includes the body parameters (that's an example from the API guide):

```
BODY PARAMETER (UPLOAD IMAGE BY BASE64-ENCODED CONTENTS)
{
    "file_name": "image.png",
    "contents": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z8BQDwAEhQGAhKmMIQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
}
```

This is my code:

```
public class ImageContentsParams
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Contents { get; set; }
}

ImageContentsParams imageContents = new ImageContentsParams();
imageContents.FileName = "example.png";
byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\example.png");
imageContents.Contents = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(imageContents);

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://api.printify.com/v1/uploads/images.json");

    request.Content = jsonBody;

    using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.SendAsync(request))
    {
        // here I'm checking the returned response
    }
}
```

I keep getting the following error response from Prinify server (this is after parsing):

> Code: 10100
>   Message: Validation failed.
>   Reason:
>     file_name: The file name field is required. 
>     contents: The contents field is required when url is not present. 
>     url: The url field is required when contents is not present.

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: How `jsonBody` is defined and set?

Comment: it seems like you are having a problem in header you need to set proper header before sending request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your `FileName` in `JsonContentParams` must be renamed to be the same as the **JSON** that is expected in that service. This is because the params will be serialized and will not match with the specification of the service.

```
public class ImageContentsParams
{
    public string file_name { get; set; }
    public string contents { get; set; }
}
```

Another solution can be to add the `JsonProperty` attribute, in order to not to refactor all your code.

```
public class ImageContentsParams
{
    [JsonProperty("file_name")] 
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("contents")] 
    public string Contents { get; set; }
}
```

Try something like that and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 1):

FileName property will be serialized into **fileName** and that will not match **file_name** convention. Change the property to match or specify mapping schema on the serialization to translate FileName into file_name.
You can do the mapping by specifyng [JsonProperty("file_name")] attribute on the FileName property. Something like this:

```
public class ImageContentsParams
{
    [JsonProperty("file_name")] 
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Contents { get; set; }
}
```